# If the inclusion of a closed subspace is a homotopy equivalence, is the quotient contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question is motivated by the research for minimal hypotheses for Proposition 2.22 in Hatcher. (In particular why is not enough to assume that $A\subset X$ is a homotopy equivalence)

I know that if the homotopy equivalence/inclusion is a cofibration then $X$ deformation retracts onto $A$ and therefore $X/A$ is contractible. So my question is: does it exist an inclusion $A\subset X$ of a closed subset which is a homotopy equivalence, not a cofibration and such that $X/A$ is not contractible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$
X=(I\times\{0\})\cup (\{0\}\times I)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{1/n\}\times I
$$
topologised as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This space (or at least one very similar) is discussed in Exercise 6.(a) on p.18 of Hatcher's book. The exercise asks you to show that $X$ is contractible (and even deformation retracts to any point of $I\times\{0\}$), but does not deformation retract to the point $x=(0,1)$. In particular, the inclusion $\{x\}\hookrightarrow X$ cannot be a cofibration.

Now let $X_0,X_1$ be copies of $X$ and $Y=X_0\sqcup X_1$ their disjoint union. Put $A=\{x_0,x_1\}$, where $x_i$ for $i=0,1$ corresponds to the point $(0,1)$ of $X_i$. Since each $X_i$ is contractible, the closed inclusion $A\hookrightarrow Y$ is a homotopy equivalence. However, $Y/A$ is the [double comb space](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Double_comb_space), which is not contractible.

To finish on a positive note, here is a slight more general statement that that mentioned in your question. You can prove it yourself or look up the proof in tom Dieck's text book *Algebraic Topology*.

> Let $X$ be a space and $A\subseteq X$ a subspace. Suppose that $H:X\times I\rightarrow X$ is a homotopy such that $H_t(A)\subseteq A$ for each $t\in I$ and that $H_1$ is constant on $A$. Then the quotient projection $X\rightarrow X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.